# Localization in Xamarin.Forms 4.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, localization

We followed the guidelines for localization given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text, but this is about 3 years old.

[This post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105707/is-localization-of-resx-resources-handled-automatically-now) seems to indicate that providing the location-specific implementations of a ILocalize interface is not required anymore. But when I remove everything but the TranslateExtension class itself, only one problem remains: while it is true that now  it uses the system culture on startup, swapping in the middle of a running application (i.e. *Settings > Change Language > Return to app* causes crashing of the app (it did not crash before)

Any hints what is going on, and if the guide is still to be followed as written 3 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was asked here (and I missed it during search):
[For Xamarin.Forms localization, do I need to implement ILocalize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026519/for-xamarin-forms-localization-do-i-need-to-implement-ilocalize?rq=1)

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/782#issuecomment-422705118

So there is no need for implementing ILocalize anymore, and the docs are outdated (and have been for about a year, no one got around to updating them yet at Microsoft ...)